# 'had better not entangle' v 'had better not to entangle'

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, syntax

Can I write this sentence:

> He said Carter had better not entangle the US in problems like those
>   in Afghanistan, Somalia and Iraq.

Like this:

> He said Carter had better **to** not entangle the US in problems like those
>   in Afghanistan, Somalia and Iraq.

?

If so, what's the difference between the meaning of both sentence?

Comment: No, you cannot. In this context  you use the 'bare infinitive' version of the verb, as in sentence 1, not the 'to infinitive', as in sentence 2, which is not grammatical.

Comment: See http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/4979/21503 and http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31204/hadnt-better-had-better-not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot rewrite as you suggest.

The expression *had better* works like the modal verbs *can, may, must, shall, will*—it always takes a **bare** infinitive as its complement, not an infinitive marked with *to*.

It may help you to think of *had better* as equivalent to *should*:

> <sup>ok</sup>Carter should not entangle the US in problems.
> <sup>∗</sup> Carter should to not entangle the US in problems.
>
> <sup>ok</sup>Carter had better not entangle the US in problems.
> <sup>∗</sup> Carter had better to not entangle the US in problems.

<sup>∗</sup> *marks an ungrammatical utterance

Comment: I have no real problem with [*(You) **would do** better to not (do something)*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?tbm=bks&q=%22would+do+better+to+not%22&gws_rd=cr&ei=KFlTVs7uOsHiUq3Uk5AK), though personally I'd normally negate it as *You would do better **not to** [do that]*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's a somewhat different idiom, though: it recommends a new strategy rather than deprecating a (implicit or explicit)  proposed strategy.

Comment: Apparently [an 1897 issue of the Ohio Educational Monthly says many teachers found “had better” and other idioms “very difficult to dispose of grammatically.”](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2013/03/had-better.html) On that same page it specifically says the ***idiomatic phrase** “had better” ...  is a venerable usage with roots far back in Old English.* I can't argue with either of those points - ***I'd better not***, in fact, since although I've been brought up on the usage, I can't for the life of me deconstruct the "syntax" (which was presumably straightforward at one time).